# Boot Linux on Chromebook from external media

Tags: boot, chrome-book, chrome-os

I have full Linux installed on my flash drive. What I want to do is boot from this flash drive with the Asus C300 Chromebook.

There are many tutorials in the Internet on how to install Linux on  chromebook, but I want have the **original system untouched**. All tutorials note that I have to enable developer mode on chromebook, but I'm curious if it is necessary to such simple task as booting from flash drive.

So my question is, how to go to multiboot on chromebook, something like pressing F12 on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm curious if it is necessary to such simple task as booting from flash drive.

Such a simple task can be very complex. It assumes that all components are in place on a certain platform, but Chrome devices are no traditional BIOS/UEFI computers and some don't even have a x86 processor.

The Chrome OS developers had a different goal in mind than to make another general purpose computer like the popular "Wintel" systems. They got rid of every step in the traditional boot sequence to make Chrome OS boot fast even on low powered machines.

[image: traditional boot vs Chrome OS hardware]

<sup>Source: [Chromium OS Fast Boot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTFfl7AjNfI)</sup>

So even if you have an Intel processor in your device there should be no firmware code active to detect external storage and attempt to boot from it (you have to enable it in developer mode, as well as to boot from unsigned media). The default for Chrome OS devices is that there is a recovery system with basic functionality to deploy system updates, here is an [example statement](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/partition-resizing):

> Partition resizing is initiated by the system, not by the user.

Everything else is supposed to trigger the warning message for the user that her/his device has been tampered with. Which is good from my point of view.

Since this question has been posted the traditional Windows platform (Windows on Intel processors = Wintel) switched from legacy BIOS firmware to UEFI, which doesn't make it easier when you say I installed Linux (for x86/x64) on a flash drive, because there are two different ways you can possibly boot these systems now. It doesn't stop there because chrome devices use [different methods for booting](http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/custom-firmware) as described in the developer documents.

Some users in the community like [MrChromebox/MattDevo](https://mrchromebox.tech/#bootmodes) provide custom firmwares which allow to boot other operating systems or external media (depending on the configuration you would have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) on recent x86 Chrome devices.

Comment: You are answered or explained about chromebook?

Comment: I don't understand, what were you trying to say?

Comment: @Tom Becker, You should go to BIOS setting and disable fast boot option.Make sure,you selected usb flash drive to boot it.When your BIOS can detect USB Flash drive.

Comment: @supriady No, chromebooks don't feature a setup screen/program like typical Windows machines with legacy BIOS or UEFI do. Why are you replying to my answer when your comment is addressed to the OP?